# Outline custom shape

Tags: adobe-photoshop, path, shapes, pen-tool

I was wishing to achieve [and Define] a custom **EMPTY** shape, but after creating
this hideous fish with Paths, Pen Tool, Direct Selection Tool and Stroke Path [Brush 15px], my custom shape has been saved «full», namely all black! Why?

Please, can you tell me how to achieve an empty shape with Photoshop?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create the outline path of the shape.

- If the shape is in an empty layer, holding <kbd>Cmd</kbd> (Mac) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (Windows), click the layer thumbnail to load
  the transparency selection
- From the **Paths Panel Menu**, choose **Make Work Path...**
- Use this path to create the outline shape

[image: fish]